# no view changes on BehaviorSubject but only on first page visit

Tags: angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I've wrote a table module which includes a filter module, a tab navigation module and a pagination module. This table module is implemented by different parent components like user list or message list.
The parent sends a list of objects to the table module where it'll be sent to the different child components (filter, tab navigation, pagination). [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vwd0zgJree5LrbaOARvx?p=preview) is the basic setup with pagination as only one child component.

For getting the list of messages as list of conversations, I built a conversation service where all messages are received from a server and transformed into a list of conversations. When the conversation list within the service has changed an event is fired. Because the message list component is subscribed to this event the list within message list will change, too.

```
@Injectable()
export class ConversationService {

    private conversationList: Conversation[];
    private changeConversationListSource = new Subject<any[]>();
    conversationListChanged$ = this.changeConversationListSource.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthenticationService,
        private messageService: MessageService) { }

    getConversationList() {
        if (this.conversationList)
            this.changeConversationListSource.next(this.conversationList);
        else
            this.getMessages()
                .then(messages => {
                    this.buildConversations(messages);  // conversationList built in here
                    this.changeConversationListSource.next(this.conversationList);
                });
    }

    private getMessages(): Promise<Message[]> {
        return this.messageService
                   .getMessagesByUserId(this.authService.getAuthElement().userId);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I visit the page for the first time the displayed table won't change after transforming the list within pagination. When I visit the page again, click on a tab of tab navigation or on a site button of pagination it works. This ONLY happens for the message list component and not the user list component. The strange thing is that only the table itself won't be displayed correctly, the received list of objects within the table module are correctly transformed by pagination.

[image: View when visiting the page for the first time]

As you can see the BehaviorSubject holds 3 objects but the table has 6 entries. After I click on any button as described above, the view changes correctly.

[image: View after any button on the page has clicked]

When I don't do an API call in ConversationService it works.

```
getConversationList() {
    this.changeConversationListSource.next([
        new Conversation(),
        new Conversation(),
        new Conversation(),
        new Conversation(),
        new Conversation(),
        new Conversation()
    ]);
}
```

So what could cause this problem?

**Update 1**

Here is the code for building the conversation list.

```
private buildConversations(messages: Message[]): void {
    let conversations: Conversation[] = [];     // 
    let users = this.groupUsers(messages);      // 
    conversations = conversations.concat(       // 
        this.buildConversationList(users.internUsers, messages));
    conversations = conversations.concat(       // 
        this.buildConversationList(users.externUsers, messages));
    this.conversationList = conversations;
}

private buildConversationList(users: any[], messages: Message[]): Conversation[] {
    let conversations: Conversation[] = [];
    let conversation: Conversation;
    users.forEach(user => {
        for (let category in MessageCategory) {
            conversation = new Conversation();
            conversation.category = MessageCategory[category];
            if (typeof user === 'string') conversation.externPartner = user;
            else conversation.internPartner = user;
            conversation.messages = messages.filter(message => {
                    if (message.category === MessageCategory[category])
                        if (typeof user === 'string')
                            return this.checkExternMessage(message, user, conversation);
                        else
                            return this.checkInternMessage(message, user, conversation);
            });
            if (conversation.messages.length > 0) conversations.push(conversation);
        }
    });
    return conversations;
}

private checkExternMessage(message: Message, user: string, conversation: Conversation): boolean {
    if (message.receiver === undefined && message.sender === undefined)
        if (message.receiverMail !== null && message.receiverMail === user) {
            if (!message.isRead && this.messageService.isUserMessageReceiver(message))
                conversation.newMessages++;
            return true;
        }
        else if (message.senderMail !== null && message.senderMail === user) {
            if (!message.isRead && this.messageService.isUserMessageReceiver(message))
                conversation.newMessages++;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

private checkInternMessage(message: Message, user: User, conversation: Conversation): boolean {
    if (message.receiver !== undefined && message.sender !== undefined)
        if (message.receiver !== null && message.receiver.id === user.id) {
            if (!message.isRead && this.messageService.isUserMessageReceiver(message))
                conversation.newMessages++;
            return true;
        }
        else if (message.sender !== null && message.sender.id === user.id) {
            if (!message.isRead && this.messageService.isUserMessageReceiver(message))
                conversation.newMessages++;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

**Update 2**

During finding the bug within `this.buildConversations()` I recognized that the error can't be within this function. When I do the following I get the same bug as before.

```
private buildConversations(messages: Message[]): void {
    let conversations: Conversation[] = [];
    let users = this.groupUsers(messages);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        conversations.push(new Conversation());
    this.conversationList = conversations;
}
```

So it definitely looks like the bug appears during the API call, but there I can't find any error. Here is the code of the API call.

```
@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private newMessages: number;
    newMessagesChanged: EventEmitter<number>;

    constructor(
        private authService: AuthenticationService,
        private httpClient: HttpClient) {
        this.newMessagesChanged = new EventEmitter<number>();
    }

    getMessagesByUserId(userId: number): Promise<Message[]> {
        if (this.messages)
            return new Promise<Message[]>((resolve, reject) => resolve(this.messages));
        return this.httpClient
                   .get(MessageService.API + userId, this.httpClient.getHeader())
                   .then(res => this.handleMessageList(this.httpClient.extractData(res)));
    }

    private handleMessageList(messages: Message[]): Message[] {
        this.newMessages = 0;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.messages.forEach(message => {
            if (!message.isRead && this.isUserMessageReceiver(message))
                this.newMessages++;
        });
        this.newMessagesChanged.emit(this.newMessages);
        return this.messages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for this.buildConversations(messages) ?

Comment: @MikeOne of course, I updated the question.

Comment: Okay, and you're using an async pipe in your template to subscribe to that Subject (which btw, is not a behaviorSubject but a normal Subject)?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, I did it exactly like in the plunker. And it is a BehaviorSubject not in ConversationService but in TableComponent where the list is displayed.

Comment: @user289520. Do you still need help with this?